# How to use this url (with PORT) in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

[This is what they gave me (click here to see the screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qpUf.png)

I was in a hackathon, and my teammate decided to use Amazon web service as our database. Later, one of them gave an url with port (which I think it is the url to the database). So I tried to use this url in my iOS app, but I don't know how to??

As I realize this is important for building my app, any help would be highly appreciated

[This is how my teammate dealt with it (the language is JavaScript)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stHma.png)

Comment: URL: hackteams.c6p7kpyzcymg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
PORT: 3306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hackteams.c6p7kpyzcymg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306

user, password and database to be sent as parameters